# Control-Option-Space key to open a Popup in a JCombobox in MAC with Voiceover utility

Tags: java, macos, swing, jcombobox, key-bindings

I have a `JComboBox` with multiple values in it. How to detect the keystroke `control-option-space` to open a pop-up window of `JComboBox` in MAC?

Comment: Your recent [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13410975/revisions) may represent a new question; for testing, I've added an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) below; please reference this Q&A if you post elsewhere, e.g. [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/71915/20589).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear if you want the `control-option-space` key binding in addition to, or instead of, the standard `space` key. In either case, you can evoke the `aquaSpacePressed` action using a binding such as the one shown below. See *How to Use Key Bindings* for details.

```
combo.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE,
        KeyEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK),
    "aquaSpacePressed");
```

Because this is Mac-specific, you may want to use a predicate such as this:

```
System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS X")
```

Addendum: The [sscce](http://sscce.org/) below was used to test the scenario in the revised question.

Addendum: For reasons that are not clear, enabling `System Preferences > Speech > Text to Speech` preempts the `control-option-space` binding. As an alternative, you can bind to the standard `Action`, `"spacePopup"`, shown in the revised example below.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13412208/230513
 */
public class ComboKeyTest extends JPanel {

    public ComboKeyTest() {
        JComboBox cpmbo = new JComboBox();
        cpmbo.addItem("One");
        cpmbo.addItem("Two");
        cpmbo.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE,
            KeyEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK),
            "spacePopup");

        this.add(cpmbo);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("NewJavaGUI");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ComboKeyTest().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works absolutely fine for me.
But there is one more issue where i need to use this shortcut key when the voice over utility is running. 
I am finding difficulty in opening the popup with the voice over utility.

Comment: You might check System Preferences for a conflicting Keyboard Shortcut.

Comment: I have verified it with some of the items in system preference like 'dictation & Speech' where drop down list popups with the control-option-space even though voice over utility is running.

Comment: `META_DOWN_MASK` and `SHIFT_DOWN_MASK` are also available.

Comment: Basically voice over utility will guide to operate with the specific key 'control-option-space' to open a pop up. So i am not supposed to change it to other option.

Comment: What key is set in `System Preferences > Speech > Text to Speech`?

Comment: Ok, Even above Test code works fine without voice over utility but with Voice over utility its failing to open the popup.

Comment: Even i have observed that if we change either of the  KeyEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK or KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK to anything else like KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK it will work with VoiceOver